# Counting the occurence of a string after a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am working on a personal project, with Javascript. I am at an intermediary level. 
I have created a for loop that gives me a list of random numbers. For each "i", there is one pair of integers. The integers are always positive, different and within a certain range (ex. between 1 and 10). 
Let's say after I run the loop, I get this:

```
1 vs 3
4 vs 7
5 vs 8
2 vs 3
7 vs 5
3 vs 4
1 vs 2
3 vs 5
3 vs 1
5 vs 7
... and so on...
```

Now, how do I count the occurence of each pair of occurence. For example, I would like to be able to have:

```
3 vs 1: occurred 2 times
7 vs 5: occurred 2 times
3 vs 5: occurred 1 time

And so on...
```

The order does not matter, so I consider that 3 vs 1 and 1 vs 3 is the same thing. I realize that may complicate things.

Comment: Why dont you post the code?

Comment: show your `intermediary level` code

Comment: Would it not be easier to store numbers as int not strings and just create an multidimensional array that you can then count through and find occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Generate Pairs
var randomPairs = []
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  var randomPair = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1]
  randomPairs.push(randomPair)
}

// Count Pairs
var randomPairsCounted = []
for (var i = 0; i < randomPairs.length; ++i) {
  var a = randomPairs[i][0]
  var b = randomPairs[i][1]
  if (a > b) {
    var t = a
    a = b
    b = t
  }
  var doublicate = false
  for (var j = 0; j < randomPairsCounted.length; ++j) {
    if (randomPairsCounted[j][0] == a && randomPairsCounted[j][1] == b) {
      randomPairsCounted[j][2]++
      doublicate = true
      break
    }
  }
  if (doublicate == false) {
    randomPairsCounted.push([a, b, 1])
  }
}

// Demo Output
document.write("Pairs: " + JSON.stringify(randomPairs) + "<br><br>")
for (var i = 0; i < randomPairsCounted.length; ++i) {
  document.write(randomPairsCounted[i][0] + " vs " + randomPairsCounted[i][1] + 
                 ": occured " + randomPairsCounted[i][2] + " time" + 
                 (randomPairsCounted[i][2] == 1 ? "" : "s") + "<br>")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much CodeiSir, this is great! I had thought about using arrays, and this makes complete sense :)